# Executar programa Java com PHP e retornar Saída do Console

Tags: php, java

Preciso executar um programa Java que está no meu servidor, por exemplo `Teste.java` e retornar a saída do console resultante da execução, seja um erro, ou uma frase como `Olá Mundo!`, utilizando PHP.

Já utilizei comandos como `exec("java Teste", $output)` e `system("java Teste", $output)`, e realmente conseguia executar o programa, mas nunca conseguia retornar a saída do console que esse programa gerava.

Há alguma forma de fazer a execução desse programa, e retornar a saída dele?

Comment: Com o comando `system("java Teste", $output)` é possível exibir no console o retorno do seu código java. Tenta executar um `java Teste` direto no console para verificar se ele retorna algum erro. Você compilou sua classe ??

Comment: Após fazer o que sugeriu o @Oliveira, tente.
exec("java Teste", $output);
var_dump($output);

Comment: @Oliveira, sim eu compilei minha classe, via `system("javac C:\Users\Desktop\Hello.java", $saida);`, também fiz a compilação via console só para garantir. Mas quando tento executar o código com `system("java C:\Users\Desktop\Hello", $saida);`, e imprimo a variável saída, só é impresso o número `1`

Comment: @MarcosXavier também usei o `exec()`, mas não obtive sucesso :(

Comment: @GaMen provavelmente a sua classe não tinha sido compilada, ao executar 'system("java C:\Users\Desktop\Hello", $saida);' o retorno foi o valor 1, caso a classe tivesse sido compilada seria exibido o valor 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente seria assim:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Java Execute</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="#" method="post">

        <input name="executar" value="executar" type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <?php

    if(count($_POST) > 0) {
        $path = "/home/leonardo/workspace/Java/src/";
        $class = "HelloWorld";

        if(isset($_POST['executar'])) {
            echo "Saída: " . shell_exec("cd {$path} && java {$class}"); 

        }

    }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Se sua classe java estiver devidamente programada e compilada irá funcionar sem muitos problemas. Usei o `shell_exec` por ser mais simples, passa para ele o comando, que é, entrando no caminho da minha classe e executando o arquivo `.class` compilado dela.

P.S.: Vejo que não compilou sua classe, execute o comando `javac Classe.java` para compilar.

A classe usada no exemplo foi:

```
public class HelloWorld 
{

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
                System.out.println("Ola, Stack Overflow!");

        }

}
```

Comment: @Ivcs kra, sua resposta é quase perfeita, realmente quando eu executo o programa, eu recebo a saída, muito obrigado. Mas supondo que eu estivesse tentando compilar um código com algum erro, teria como eu retornar esse erro? Porque utilizando seu exemplo, se eu utilizo o `javac` em uma classe com algum problema, digamos a falta de um`;`, a saída é nula. Mas novamente, obrigado pela solução!

Comment: @GaMen Você pode usar ` 2>&1` no fim de cada comando pra forçar uma resposta

Comment: @Ivics Novamente, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente! Cara, não tenho palavras para descrever o quanto você ajudou, vlw mesmo.